# The "Material Design Components" aren't being rendered in the layout previewer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, mdc-components

In all of my android apps, I implemented the *Material Design Components* (MDC) dependency for `AndroidX` and everything was working fine **until I updated Android Studio to the 3.4** stable version.
The app compiles and runs perfectly in both emulators and real phones, but the **XML Layout Previewer** of Android Studio **doesn't render any of the MDC** and the Preview page just freezes.

I have already tried many things and none has fixed my problem:

- Updating to Android Studio 3.5 Canary or Dev
- Changing the `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersions` to 28
- Reinstall Android Studio
- Invalidate cache and restart
- Use different `Theme.MaterialComponents` variants

This XML Layout Previewer problem **ONLY OCCURS** in layouts that have at least 1 MDC in it. If there is non of those components everything works fine.

My `styles.xml` file looks like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorGroupPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorGroupPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorGroupAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_bg</item
</style>
```

Even if I extend the `AppTheme` to be `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` it's not working.

My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        maxSdkVersion 28
        ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    ...
}
```

### Example of a layout that doesn't render

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".Activities.AddNoteActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorGroupPrimaryDark">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/addNote_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingStart="6dp"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:title="@string/addNotes_toolbar"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.CACH.Title"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/addNote_titleInput"
            style="@style/Widget.CACH.TextInputLayout.Primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:hint="@string/addNotes_title"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/addNote_titleText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the example, the Toolbar and AppBar don't cause any trouble, but at the moment I added the `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` the previewer freezed. If in another layout I add a `MaterialButton` or `FloatingActionButton` or `MaterialCardView` same thing happens.

(In the example, all of the `style` attributes extend a MaterialComponent theme that's specific for the component. Example: `TextInputLayout` style has as parent `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox`)

### Thanks for your answers!!

Comment: Can you put an example of a layout that doesn't render in the Preview window?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @JawadAhmed I tried it and didn't work. It solved the problem temporarily but after a few minutes it freezed again

Comment: I have the feeling you may have a faulty installation. Have you tried all answers in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594881/android-studio-not-rendering-layout-preview

Comment: It seems like the xml layout previewer can't draw com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout. I'm looking for a solution, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a complete solution to this problem, but what I tried out and worked perfectly every time was downloading **AndroidStudio 3.5 Beta**. Using that version of the IDE solved all the issues I had with MaterialComponents.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, Just downgrade material lib to alpha-04. Now alpha 7 is latest version but from alpha 05 til 07 this issue exists.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I switched the theme from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
```

To:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
```

Maybe that's to the definitive solution but it's a good workaround for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually tried that and it worked for some components but other became gray even if you changed some attributes. So in my case it was a partial solution.

Comment: I also found using the Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge theme fixed the issue, but some components need to be restyled a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Since I updated Android Studio 3.3 to 3.4 version, AppbarLayout made rendering problem issue and caused Javalang exception like this picture. I am still searching for the solution
[image]